# Unable to git clone from windows git server

Tags: git

I setup git server on my windows machine, I am able to ssh to it with password and navigate through files and folders: 
`ssh user@10.0.1.10`
then I created a bare repository in `C:/Git/test.git`
so from my mac, I am trying to clone the repository: `git clone user@10.0.1.10:/C/Git/test.git`
But I am getting an error message after entering the password:

```
fatal: '/C/Git/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
 Solution was this: `git clone user@10.0.1.10:/Git/test/git`
Thank you for support guys!

Comment: Did you run `git daemon` in `/C/Git/test.git`?

Comment: yes, it does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Mac, try first:

```
ssh user@10.0.1.10 ls /C/Git/test.git
# or
ssh user@10.0.1.10 ls /c/Git/test.git
```

That will validate that you do have access to that bare repository folder, and that the case of the path is the correct one (in particular, the drive letter might be lowercase)

The [OP Nodir Nasirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4635750/nodir-nasirov) confirms a path issue [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55896406/unable-to-git-clone-from-windows-git-server/55897118?noredirect=1#comment98450540_55897118):

> Apparently, I did not `c`, solution was
>
> ```
> git clone user@10.0.1.20:/Git/test.git
> ```

Comment: apperently I did not `c`, solution was `git clone user@10.0.1.20:/Git/test.git`

Comment: @NodirNasirov Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.